# GHDL hangs running testbench

Tags: vhdl, fpga, ghdl

When testing a simple game of life implementation in VHDL, the GHDL simulation of the empty test-bench hangs with 100% CPU usage, after printing out the "End of test" message.

Here is the code:

```
----- Package ------------------------------
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package data_types is
    type array2D is array (0 to 10, 0 to 10) of std_logic;
end data_types;


----- Main Code ----------------------------
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.data_types.all;

entity de0 is
    port (matrix : inout array2D);
end de0;


architecture life of de0 is

    -- Return the integer value of a cell, treating all out of bounds as 0
    function cellValue (matrix : array2D; x, y : integer) return integer is 
    begin
        if (y < 0 or y > matrix'high(1) or x < 0 or x > matrix'high(2) or matrix(y, x) = '0') then
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
        end if;
    end cellValue;

begin

    -- Iterate over all cells
    row: for y in matrix'range(1) generate
        column: for x in matrix'range(2) generate

            process

                variable neighbours : integer := cellValue(matrix, x - 1, y - 1) +
                                                cellValue(matrix, x - 1, y) +
                                                cellValue(matrix, x - 1, y + 1) +
                                                cellValue(matrix, x, y - 1) +
                                                cellValue(matrix, x, y + 1) +
                                                cellValue(matrix, x + 1, y - 1) +
                                                cellValue(matrix, x + 1, y) +
                                                cellValue(matrix, x + 1, y + 1);

            begin

                -- Update the cell value according to the game of life rules
                if (neighbours = 2 or neighbours = 3) then
                    matrix(y, x) <= '1';
                else
                    matrix(y, x) <= '0';
                end if;

            end process;

        end generate;
    end generate;

end life;
```

And the testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.data_types.all;

entity life_tb is
end life_tb;

architecture behaviour of life_tb is
    component life
        port (matrix : inout array2D);
    end component;

    for test: life use entity work.de0;
    signal matrix : array2D;

begin

    test: life port map (matrix => matrix);

    process
    begin
            assert false
                report "End of test" severity note;

            wait;

    end process;
end behaviour;
```

Comment: The report in the assertion statement will actually occur immediately once, then never again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process in life of de0 has neither a sensitivity list, nor a wait statement, so this process will run forever, just executing the statements in the process in an infinite loop at the same simulation time, and the simulation will therefore not stop.

You can fix this by adding a sensitivity list `(matrix)`, or a wait with some condition.

Comment: There are two conditions that can cause ghdl to end a simulation.  The first is a lack of signal transactions, the second is through the use of a run time option providing a stop-time  Neither condition appears to be met in the model.  Without consuming simulation time the model is limited to report statements for conveying information on sequential state. If the model were to become timed it would be possible to determine why it's a perfect relaxation oscillator (and it appears to be the function cellValue) by storing waveforms.  It'd require a stop-time then.

Comment: I originally had the clock in the sensitivity list, so that it would update on each clock signal, however I don't know how to simulate the clock in the test-bench (manually toggling clk didn't seem to work). How would I do that or should I use a wait instead?

Comment: @DavidKoontz: Provided my model is correct I don't see where there would be any signal transitions at all in this test-bench. Could you explain why this is not the case?

Comment: @alexdavey - sounds like you could post another question "how do I create a clock in my testbench?"...

Comment: @MartinThompson - I have found the answer [here](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.sg/2010/03/how-to-write-testbench.html). Do you think I should post a question (it would be self-answered, unless someone else has a better solution).

Comment: @alexdavey:  function cellValue returns 1 for all non-border states, the neighbors count with exceed the 2 or 3 neighbors threshold and you'll assign the maxtrix(x,y) location to '0'.  From IEEE Std 1076-1993, Glossary, B.5 active driver: A driver that acquires a new value during a simulation cycle regardless of whether the new value is different from the previous value. (§ 12.6.2 , § 12.6.4 [The simulation cycle]). After the second simulation cycle the model would hang if matrix was in the sensitivity list or a wait target because of no new events (B.88 glossary, the same value is assigned).

Comment: @alexdavey: I'm not a big fan of that website (I've found myself disagreeing with too much of it, that page in particular isn't a great example of a testbench IMHO :)  Certainly post the question about creating clocks, I'm sure there'll be several answers (in fact, that question might already have been asked... but I can't find it atm :(

Answer (score 5):

This supplements MortenZdk's fine answer.  It's simply too big to go in comments and doesn't change that answer.  It does demonstrate how to make your model clocked as well as how to stop it from running continuously.

Placing  matrix is the sensitivity list of the unlabeled process in de0(life)

```
            process (matrix)
```

gives:

```
ghdl -a de0.vhdl
ghdl -a life_tb.vhdl
ghdl -e life_tb
ghdl -r life_tb
life_tb.vhdl:22:13:@0ms:(assertion note): End of test
```

The assertion test executes only once and immediately, it doesn't signal the end of test.

Note the model quit executing but we have no idea how may simulation cycles it took.  The idea behind simulation time is to allow waveforms to be stored as well as relative time to be quantized.

Adding a clock to the simulation:

In the architecture declarative region we declare the clock signal:

```
    signal clk: std_logic;
```

You can add a new process to generate a clock in your testbench (life_tb.vhdl):

```
CLOCK:
    process 
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= '1';
    end process;
```

It has a 20 ns period and the first positive edge is 10 ns into the simulation.

We add the clock to port on life:

```
    component life
        port (
            matrix :    inout   array2D;
            clk:        in      std_logic
    );
    end component;
```

We update the de0 entity to use the clk:

```
entity de0 is
port (
    matrix : inout array2D;
    clk:      in   std_logic
);
```

We update the process to be sensitive to clk and to be timed:

```
            process (clk)

            variable neighbours : integer := cellValue(matrix, x - 1, y - 1) +
                                            cellValue(matrix, x - 1, y) +
                                            cellValue(matrix, x - 1, y + 1) +
                                            cellValue(matrix, x, y - 1) +
                                            cellValue(matrix, x, y + 1) +
                                            cellValue(matrix, x + 1, y - 1) +
                                            cellValue(matrix, x + 1, y) +
                                            cellValue(matrix, x + 1, y + 1);

        begin
            if clk'event and clk = '1' then
            -- Update the cell value according to the game of life rules
                if (neighbours = 2 or neighbours = 3) then
                    matrix(y, x) <= '1';
                else
                    matrix(y, x) <= '0';
                end if;
            end if;
```

Now because clk is a free running oscillator we need to use stop-time:

```
ghdl -a de0.vhdl
ghdl -a life_tb.vhdl
ghdl -e life_tb
ghdl -r life_tb --stop-time=100ns --wave=life_tb.ghw
life_tb.vhdl:35:13:@0ms:(assertion note): End of test
ghdl:info: simulation stopped by --stop-time
```

[image: clocked life simulation]

If you scroll through the maxtrix elements we find that the four corners of the matrix are set to '1' at the first clock event.  All the remaining elements are set to '0'.

The second clk event shown at the cursor doesn't assign new values to any matrix elements (the four matrix corners each see three neighbors, they are stable).

If the matrix were in the process sensitivity list instead your simulation would stop after the second time around (un-clocked).

And the point of a timed simulation is that it allows you to peer into the simulation by examining waveforms, in this case with gtkwave.  The alternative is assertion and/or report statements, but in an un-timed simulation these will occur on cycle boundaries and there is no guarantee of order if they are not sequential statements in the same process.

And you could note without modifying your original code other than the assertion statement evaluating for matrix'event in the testbench you could get your model to stop simulating.  You'd want to change the threshold for stopping the simulation with the run time option (e.g. --assert-level=warning, where the assertion for a lack of matrix'event is a warning. (And the assertion would signify the actual End of test).

Fixing cellValue is as they say an exercise left to the reader.  (As in how or why did the matrix corners get set in the first place?)

The interesting part is telling when your model is quiescent when timed.  You can use matrix'event to toggle a signal (use it as clock) and use the clock to test for two successive occurrences of the same value of that signal.  And of course the signal can be used in an assertion statement with assert-level to end the simulation when quiescent.

Synthesizable hardware is a bit more involved.